Verbal declaration to raise question
In my home game Player A said raise Player B thought he said check (Player B not paying attention).
Player B said raise also Player A just get mad and mucked his cards. Player B said Player A still had to raise because he said raise
What should I have done?

Technically verbal declarations are always binding. So in the situation, regardless of Player B paying attention or not Player A is bound to raise. I'll give you an example here, if Player A said raise, and didn't say an amount, and then Player B said raise after, technically Player B is bound to raise, as is Player A. However, because Player A didn't say an amount, he or she could min raise, i.e. if you're playing 1/2, Player A would have to make it 4. Now if Player A said raise 100, they'd have to make it 100.
However as I always say in these situations, it is a home game. Do what is best for the game. What I mean here is, if you're all friends, and it's for small amounts of money and a chance to have some fun hanging out with your friends is it really worth causing an argument over such a small thing. Often in these situations it's best to just let it go the first time, move on and just be clear that in future a raise will be enforced. You could also make the argument that Player B was perhaps angle shooting here (hard to actually prove if they were or weren't paying attention), but in anycase the warning can also apply to Player B of telling them to wait for their turn until action has completed.
So in summary, technically yes Player A is bound to a raise, although if no amount was said it is a min raise. However due to a home game situation do what is right for the context of the game and relationship with the people.
